# Spring R2DBC Compatibility with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-webflux, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.5

So, I have this spring reactive API with these dependencies and configuration to persist data in a local Postgres database:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>r2dbc-postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I left out other dependencies as they are not relevant to my question.

application.yml

```
spring:
  r2dbc:
    url: r2dbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
    username: postgres
    password: password
```

These values in the yml file are all correct. I have confirmed that.

On hitting a post endpoint, I get this error: 'Failed to obtain R2DBC Connection; nested exception is io.r2dbc.postgresql.PostgresqlConnectionFactory$PostgresConnectionException: [08003] Cannot connect to localhost/:5432] with root cause'.

After couple of research, I haven't found a fix (even in the official spring doc). How do I fix this? Regards.

EDIT:
Here id the stacktrace (as requested).

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'reactor.core.publisher.Mono reactor.core.publisher.Mono.singleOptional()'
    at io.r2dbc.postgresql.SingleHostConnectionFunction.getCredentials(SingleHostConnectionFunction.java:72) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-1.0.4.RELEASE.jar:1.0.4.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.postgresql.SingleHostConnectionFunction.lambda$connect$2(SingleHostConnectionFunction.java:48) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-1.0.4.RELEASE.jar:1.0.4.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelayUntil$DelayUntilCoordinator.subscribeNextTrigger(MonoDelayUntil.java:292) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelayUntil$DelayUntilCoordinator.onNext(MonoDelayUntil.java:187) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:249) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.complete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:292) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:187) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:236) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.success(MonoCreate.java:172) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.netty.resources.NewConnectionProvider$NewConnectionObserver.onStateChange(NewConnectionProvider.java:185) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.22.jar:1.0.22]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelActive(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:62) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.22.jar:1.0.22]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:230) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:216) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:209) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelActive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1398) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:230) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:216) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelActive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:895) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractEpollChannel.java:658) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:691) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.epollOutReady(AbstractEpollChannel.java:567) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:477) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:385) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]

2024-02-14 07:44:37.628 ERROR 486005 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Failed to obtain R2DBC Connection; nested exception is io.r2dbc.postgresql.PostgresqlConnectionFactory$PostgresConnectionException: [08003] Cannot connect to localhost/<unresolved>:5432] with root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'reactor.core.publisher.Mono reactor.core.publisher.Mono.singleOptional()'
    at io.r2dbc.postgresql.SingleHostConnectionFunction.getCredentials(SingleHostConnectionFunction.java:72) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-1.0.4.RELEASE.jar:1.0.4.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.postgresql.SingleHostConnectionFunction.lambda$connect$2(SingleHostConnectionFunction.java:48) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-1.0.4.RELEASE.jar:1.0.4.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelayUntil$DelayUntilCoordinator.subscribeNextTrigger(MonoDelayUntil.java:292) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelayUntil$DelayUntilCoordinator.onNext(MonoDelayUntil.java:187) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:249) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.complete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:292) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:187) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:236) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.success(MonoCreate.java:172) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.netty.resources.NewConnectionProvider$NewConnectionObserver.onStateChange(NewConnectionProvider.java:185) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.22.jar:1.0.22]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelActive(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:62) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.22.jar:1.0.22]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:230) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:216) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:209) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelActive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1398) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:230) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:216) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelActive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:895) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractEpollChannel.java:658) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:691) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.epollOutReady(AbstractEpollChannel.java:567) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:477) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:385) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Are you sure that postgresql is up in running ?

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace instead of a snippet, also make sure that postgresql is running at your local machine and on that specific port.

Comment: yes. Postgres is active (confirmed after running 'sudo systemctl status postgresql' on my pc). I have editted the question to show the stacktrace.

Comment: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` seem quite clear. You are using incompatible versions. I wonder what you are managing, but for starters remove the `version` from the `r2dbc-postgresql` (I suspect that would be managed by Spring Boot to get a compatible version). If that doesn't solve it please add your full `pom.xml`.